# How to calculate this constant in various easing functions?

Tags: constants, easing, easing-functions

Based on this [blog post](http://void.heteml.jp/blog/archives/2014/05/easing_magicnumber.html) (japanese, so I used google translate to read that) and other various source, it's seems that the magic constant `1.70158` equal 10% "bounce". The constant appear in various easing functions such as inBack, outBack, ...

How did one come up with this constant, and how to calculate it ?

Comment: That link you’ve just posted explains step by step how the author got to that number, can you clarify what precisely you don’t understand? I’m not sure this is really a programming question.

Comment: The post ended up with 1.7015401988668, so I'm not sure if it accurate.

Comment: The post also comments on that.

Comment: So should I replace 1.70158 with that new constant in the code ?

Comment: How much difference do you realistically think that would make?! I would imagine such a small tweak would be imperceptible in practice. Is there actually a *problem* you’re trying to solve?

Comment: I guess no. As I did not understand the post clearly because of lack of English and thought that google translate may translate wrong sometimes... Thank for help...

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but here's a function to calculate it:

```
function calc(p)
    p = p/10
    local m = (27*40^2*-27*p+2*(-27*p)^3-9*40*-27*p*-54*p)/(54*40^3)
    local r = (m^2+((3*40*-54*p-(-27*p)^2)/(9*40^2))^3)^0.5
    local s = (-m+r)^(1/3)+(-m-r)^(1/3)-(-27*p)/(3*40)
    return s, 1-(s+3)/(3*s+3)
end
```